# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous while dealing with 'Nan' values

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df = inputDataFrame[COLUMN_DEFAULT_STATUS]
df = df.fillna(0)
for row in range(1, rows):
  if defaultStatusColumn and df[row] == CNST.IO_DEFAULT_STATES[index]:
     # Other lines of code
```

In the column "COLUMN_DEFAULT_STATUS", there are many 'NaN' values which I filled with '0', since my If condition was giving ValueError. Even after filling it with zeroes I still see the following error:

> **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: hi can you include data, so I can reproduce the problem? Thanks!

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with NaN entries. It comes from `df[row] == CNST.IO_DEFAULT_STATES[index]` which is not a boolean but a series and needs to be reduced to a boolean (I think `.all()` is what you want here, for all the values to be equal).

Comment: Sure, df has 189 rows which are all of 'Nan' values except for row-51-56, value = OUT

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `NaN` elements in your data. You should focus on the line the error is raised, which should be the following:

```
df[row] == CNST.IO_DEFAULT_STATES[index]
```

which is not a boolean, but a series, which needs to be reduced to a boolean in order for this to work.

If you want to check that all the values are equal, then you could use `.all()` as @Learningisamess commented.